# Google Form with script triggered on submit not working always

Tags: google-apps-script

So I have issue with script created for Google Form. It is triggered on submit. Every now and there (like once every 5 submits) it is not triggered. We tested and it is not about data provided cause we retyped data and it worked. We tested on multiple computers (for people with and without access to the form). We used multiple browsers ( fire fox, chrome, Edge, Explorer ) and for all of that it is completely random.

I tried recreation of trigger and creation of new version of script. Nothing helps. When it is not triggered script doesn't throw any errors. It is like it was never triggered.

The code just takes data from form put them into variable and send it with api.fetch to other system. I am sending mail during code to see if it works and no email and no changes in end system is visible.

Comment: Does this behavior occur when multiple users submit their form within a narrow time frame? Otherwise you'll need to provide your code for troubleshooting.

Comment: I will check that narrow time frame and code soon.